# google charts with interpolated line charts

Tags: javascript, charts

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

I am using google line charts show above, I want to have multiple lines but one line might have data on a time that the other data doesn't.

So, basically is there an option that would let me do something like..

```
data.addRows([
      ['2004', 1000, 400],
      ['2005', null, 460],
      ['2006',  860, null],
      ['2007', 1030, 540]
]);
```

and have a line that goes through `(2004, 1000)` and `(2005, 860)` instead of `(2004, 1000)` to `(2005, 0)` to `(2006, 860)`? Thanks

Comment: nope, I should of asked this to the charts teams while I was interning at google.. darn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For line charts you can use the interpolateNulls option mentioned [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

Setting it to true will make it interpolate the appropriate value.